# Problem with LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a xml

```
<MyRoot>
  <ITEM>
    <Created>Customer created Aug 22 2011  9:28AM
Contact Details Last Updated Aug 22 2011  9:39AM</Created>
    <Name>SomeName</Name>
    <Address>High way to hell</Address>
    <Phone1>123456</Phone1>
    <Phone2></Phone2>
    <Mobile>654321</Mobile>
    <Email>myemail@gmail.com</Email>
  </ITEM>
</MyRoot>
```

and it's a value of xdoc ([System.RuntimeType]  {System.Xml.Linq.XDocument} System.RuntimeType)

When I execute this:

```
var items= xdoc.Root.Elements("Item");
```

i get element of type

```
{System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetElements>d__11} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

and with 0 as number of elements.

How can I get collection of items ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML is case-sensitive.

```
var items= xdoc.Root.Elements("ITEM");
```